# Excluding repeated calculating the results of return value from class inside loop

Tags: python

The code repeats calculating the returned lists x, y, z from class (XYZ) for each round inside the (S) class loop, and that is time consuming. How could I get those lists out of the loop? EXPLAINING: to get S you need W and to get W you need to get x, y, z from XYZ (but x, y, z lists are constant value, and no need to recalculate them each round of S) Here is the code:

```
class XYZ('there is some other classes here'):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def get_x_y_z(self):
        x = []
        y = []
        z = []
        ##some input values and used the inherited class##
        return x,y,z

class W(XYZ):
    def __init__(self):
        #####

    def get_w(self, xx, n):
        x_y_z = XYZ.get_x_y_z(self)
        x = x_y_z[0]
        y = x_y_z[1]
        z = x_y_z[2]
        X = [] # this is a calculated list
        # u is a list calculated based on xx and n
        u=[]
        for i in range(0, len(xx)):
            if xx[i] > X[n]:
                break
            else:
                u.append(xx[i])
        # w = f(x,y,z)+..., but here is a brief formula
        a = x*y*z
        return a, u

# this function for plot my results
class S(W):
    def __init__(self):
        #####

    def get_s(self):
        global a, u #python adviced to add this global values
        X = [] # this is a calculated list
        l = len(X)
        N = 3
        while N <= l:
            xx = []
            for i in range(X[0], X[N]):
                xx.append(i)
            a_u = W.get_w(self, xx, N)
            a = a_u[0]
            u = a_u[1]
            
            plot(u,a)

            N = N + 1
```

Comment: I don't see where the x, y, z values are repeatedly calculated in this code.

Comment: When I run Class S , to get the result of s, the code repeat calculating x,y,z for each i

Comment: As far as I can tell, this happens in `W.get_w`, which is outside the loop `for i in range(n):`.

Comment: `s.append(s)` you append s into itself, that is not good

Comment: Yes, that happens in W.get_w and I don't know how I can get around it. Even W.get_w is out of the loop but the code still repeat all calculation every time inside loop. could I add this class inside __init__ and use it as self.w, but I don't know if it is possible to return values from class inside __init__

Comment: @Copperfield, I see, but my problem is repeating unnecessary calculation in class(S)

Comment: you can't return values from `__init__` but you can save whatever value you calculate on it inside your class instance by doing `self.myvalue = some_expensive_calculatio(...)`

Comment: @Copperfield, could you tell me where should I add self.myvalue in my code

Comment: @Mohamed in your `__init__` or wherever you need it...

Comment: @Copperfield, thank you, but still don't know how I can use it. I mean should I add it inside XYZ class. if it is possible, could you add this function to my code.

Comment: @Mohamed I wouldn't know where could be better because your example code isn't very illustrative

Comment: @Copperfield,Thanks again, my longest part in my code is calculating x,y,z lists, and I need these lists in my class S without repeating each loop. If you kindly add self.myvalue inside __init__ and I can have an idea how I can use it, then I could change the place of it if necessary.

Comment: The issue you mentioned (`get_x_y_z` is called several times when `get_s` is called) is not present in the code. You should add a [example].

Answer (score 1):

To avoid repeating expensive calculation or unnecessary repetitions there a several ways, like restructuring your code such you do those only once or use some type memorization like saving your result into a dictionary to mention one such technique.

With classes you can also save the result withing the instance of your class

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self,...):
        ...
        self.myvalue = some_expensive_calculation_or_something_to_use_a_lot(...)

    def do_something(self,...):
        #do something with self.myvalue 
        ...
        return result
```

You mention that your x,y,z list are constant, if so and those are independent of anything else and you don't change them, then you could put them as global variables

```
def get_x_y_z():
    #do something
    return x,y,z

x,y,z = get_x_y_z()

def get_w(...):
    #do something with x,y,z
    return w

def get_s(...):
    w = get_w(...)
    s = []
    for i in range(...)
        v = #do something with w, i, etc
        s.append(v)
    return s
```

if they are dependent of something, then you calculate then when necessary

**UPDATE**:

given your update, then there is a simple solution, change your list x,y,z to be an argument you give to get_w function and calculate them on S, I also added some other minor adjustments to your sample code

```
class W(XYZ):
    ...
    def get_w(self, xx, n, x_y_z):
        x,y,z = x_y_z
        ...
        return a, u
        
class S(W):
    ...
    def get_s(self):
        global a, u #python adviced to add this global values
        x_y_z = XYZ.get_x_y_z(self)
        X = [] # this is a calculated list
        for N in range(3,1+len(X)):
            xx = range(X[0], X[N])   #if you need it to be a list, then just do list(range(X[0], X[N]))
            a, u = W.get_w(self, xx, N, x_y_z)
            plot(u,a)
```

some of those adjustments include using the unpack notation in which you can assign to a collection of variables the values inside a list or similar in one line so long the number variables match the number of elements on the list

```
>>> values = [1,2,3]
>>> a,b,c = values
>>> a
1
>>> b
2
>>> c
3
>>>
```

there is no really a need to do a for loop to append the elements of a range into a list, just use the range directly that is also [Sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range) type object and support indexing and several other things that a list do, but unlike that one a range is immutable, if you need an actual list just call list on in

your `while` loop from 3 to len(X) can also be done with a range, you only need to adjust it by one

---

Another thing thing that can also be done along the lines of this adjustment in case you use this W class in something else beside this S class, is make the newly added x_y_z argument an optional argument and if not given you calculate it inside, this in order to preserver your current functionally and not break anything else

```
class W(XYZ):
    ...
    def get_w(self, xx, n, x_y_z=None):
        if x_y_z is None:
            x_y_z = XYZ.get_x_y_z(self)
        x,y,z = x_y_z
        ...
        return a, u
```

and there are some other combination you can do using the previous examples too, but I leave those as exercise

Comment: class XYZ(here there is another classes):
    def __init__(self, myvalue):
        ...
        self.myvalue = ?????(...)

    def cal_x_y_z(self):
        #do something with self.myvalue 
        ...
        return result

Comment: you're asking me if you should do that in your XYZ class? given your example, I don't know, if you think that is the best place to do it, try it and see if it work

Comment: Again, Thank you. I added some more details to my XYZ class. Now it is almost the same with my code. Could you give a hand again and tell me how I could make x,y,z  global variables. I think you first code in your answer is closer to my code

Comment: your update doesn't really help, as other mention in your sample code there is no apparent unnecessary repetition, so given that I'm inclined to think that the problem is in how you use those classes rather than the classes themselves or you just removed the problem when you simplify the code to make this sample code

Comment: @ Copperfield , I read my code again, and I tried to make it more clear. I hope that the problem is clear in the current code.

Comment: @Mohamed yes, that update does illustrate your problem much better, I added and update with a solution to it

Comment: Thank you, I am going to apply this solution in my code. Thanks very much for the advice

Comment: @ Copperfield, I modified my code, but it still loop over x,y,z for each iteration at S......

Comment: then your code does something that your sample code fail to illustrate, so there not much more I can do if I don't know what the real problem is... you need to identify were exactly you call the function that create the list x,y,z and remove it and replace it for a variable that contain those that is given by whoever call that given piece of code and so on until you create that list only once

Comment: Thank you very much, finally ,I am out of the loop, I found one more class that I used x_y_x and after replacing them, the problem has been solved. You are very helpful and informative person.